# Change CSS for checkbox and selectbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I need to implement this tool bar.
[image]

I have a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/milheiros/wo1vjpdu/1/).

This is the simple code for the checbox:

```
<label title="Tables"><span>Tables</span><input class="checkbxinput" name="check" value="check1" type="checkbox" id="table" onclick="handleClick();"/></label>
```

I've tried some solutions but I always have one of those problems:
 - The second part of the toolbar pass to a new line
 - The checkbox and the selectbox don't change at all
 - I don't want any background images in this CSS

As you can see i'm using div's. I think this is a simple question but, believe me, I can't find the correct solution for this.
If the toolbar was responsive, even better.

Anyone can give me some tips?
Thanks,
Filipe

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What doesn't work? Your demo looks ok

Comment: My demo have all controls in the same line. Great. But the checkbox don't have the layout I wanted. I've tried some styling but those change my entire line and don't change the checkbox layout.

Comment: You mean you're trying to go for that green look in your checkboxes and it doesn't work?!

Comment: Not only the green boxes but the background color and the shape of the checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Include the CSS/JS files, as well:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>StackOverFlowMenuBar</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asfCSSheets/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asfCSSheets/bootstrap-responsive.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="asfJScript/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="asfJScript/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="asfJScript/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var borderOfSelectTag   =   "";
        var txtColorSelectTag   =   "";
        function changeSelectsCSS(ggg)
        {
            borderOfSelectTag   =   document.getElementById(ggg).style.border;
            txtColorSelectTag   =   document.getElementById(ggg).style.color;
            document.getElementById(ggg).style.border   =   "2px solid #11a9ac";
            document.getElementById(ggg).style.color    =   "#11a9ac";
        }
        function removeSelectsCSS(ggg)
        {
            document.getElementById(ggg).style.border   =   borderOfSelectTag;
            document.getElementById(ggg).style.color    =   txtColorSelectTag;
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        label {
        display: inline;
        }
        .regular-checkbox {
        display: none;
        }
        .regular-checkbox + label {
        background-color: #e9ecee;
        border: 2px solid #e9ecee;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        padding: 7px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        }
        .regular-checkbox + label:active, .regular-checkbox:checked + label:active {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }
        .regular-checkbox:checked + label {
        background-color: #e9ecee;
        border: 2px solid #11a9ac;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        color: #99a1a7;
        }
        .regular-checkbox:checked + label:after {
        content: '\2714';
        font-size: 14px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1px;
        left: 2px;
        color: #11a9ac;
        }
        .big-checkbox + label {
        padding: 18px;
        }
        .big-checkbox:checked + label:after {
        font-size: 28px;
        left: 6px;
        }
        .tag {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        /*font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;*/
        display: block;
        float: left;
        }
    </style>

</head> 
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" id="ulInNav" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="nav-collapse navbar-inverse-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="ulInNav">
                        <li><a href="#" style="margin:12px 6px 6px 6px; background-color:#11a9ac;" onclick="return false;" id="clkdMnu">RELATIONS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="margin:12px 6px 6px 6px; background-color:#11a9ac;">TIME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="margin:12px 6px 6px 6px; background-color:#11a9ac;">CLUSTERS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="margin:9px 0px 6px 0px; background-color:#394263;"><div class="tag">Tables</div><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox" style="margin-top:-2px;"/><label for="checkbox-1-1"></label></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="margin:9px 0px 6px 0px; background-color:#394263;"><div class="tag">Forms</div><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-2" class="regular-checkbox" style="margin-top:-2px;"/><label for="checkbox-1-2"></label></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="margin:9px 0px 6px 0px; background-color:#394263;"><div class="tag">Menus</div><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-3" class="regular-checkbox" style="margin-top:-2px;"/><label for="checkbox-1-3"></label></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="margin:9px 0px 6px 0px; background-color:#394263;"><div class="tag">All Relations</div><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-4" class="regular-checkbox" style="margin-top:-2px;"/><label for="checkbox-1-4"></label></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="margin:9px 0px 6px 0px; background-color:#394263; max-height: 28px;"><div class="tag">Relation Type</div><select id="selectBox-1-1" style="margin-top:-5px; margin-left:10px; background-color:#e9ecee; border:2px solid #e9ecee;" onfocus="changeSelectsCSS(id);" onblur="removeSelectsCSS(id);"><option>aaa</option><option>bbb</option></select></a></li>
                        <!--<li><a href="#" style="margin:6px 0px 6px 0px; background-color:#394263; height:20px;"><select style="margin-top:-5px;"><option>aaa</option><option>bbb</option></select></a></li>-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you can see in the sample image, I need two different layouts for checkbox: before and after the onclick event. When clicked I need to show those green tics. Don't worry about what I call when I click on the checkbox. For now, I just want to manage the layout. I do not know if I made myself clear.

Comment: Is there any method through i can send you the code in folder..??

Comment: Can you put in a fiddle?

Comment: I have updated the answer but you need some CSS and JS files for that. Please tell me your email adress.

Comment: You can send to: milheiros(at)engineer.com

Comment: Thank you for your dedication. The responsiveness works fine. But my major problem is the style of the boxes. I need specific those like the sample I have.

Comment: I will try to achieve that and i will mail you when it gets accomplished. No problem. I'm new too.
Tip is visit: getbootstrap.com/2.3.2 to use other features of Bootstrap

Comment: Check your new mail, is this what you want ?
If anything else, i'm here. @milheiros

Comment: Hi Malik, Thanks again. No, isn't what I need. As you can see in the sample image, I have checkboxes with a grey background color. Also the selected box. And the boxes have a green border and tic when we select one. Is this behavior that I want.

Comment: I will try to do it. It is possible, but after duty timings. @milheiros (At about 7 PM Pakistan's standard time)

Comment: @milheiros . Your menu_bar is waiting for you. Please, check email.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some css lines to those div's: "display:inline-block" or "float:left;" Then you shouldnt have problem with new line.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put first three buttons in one div tag and next contents on second div.

Assign following css to div's.

```
.first_div{
   float: left;
   width: put width here that is cover only three buttons.
}
.second_div{
   float: left;
}
```

this will not break buttons and checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wo1vjpdu/2/)

```
.subOption span{ 
   display:inline-block; 
   vertical-align:top;  
   margin-top: 5px;
}
.subOption input[type=checkbox]{
   display:inline-block; 
   vertical-align:top;  
   margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks' Pradeep. This will help. Know, I just need to work on the layout of the boxes